# passing label value from one form to another

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a form and its subform in MS ACCESS 2007.The form has a label the value of which is passed to the subform.To make this happen I have done this: In the the main form,

```
Form_Current()

strQueryID=Me.ID.Value
```

Then I have created a new module to create a function like this:

```
Option Compare database
Option explicit
Public strQueryID As String
Public Function ValueSpareQuery() As String
ValueSpareQuery=strQueryID
End Function
```

On running the form and applying the, I find that the variable `strQueryID` is able to get the value from the main form,i.e. `strQueryID="-2143367"` but `ValueSpareQuery=""` which is empty string

I want to solve this problem. What possible reason could be behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the subform and just want to get some value from its parent form, you can do this:

```
Dim SomeVariable as String

SomeVariable = Me.Parent.ID.Value
```

...or better, if `ID` might be NULL:

```
SomeVariable = Nz(Me.Parent.ID.Value)
```

Comment: I tried to check the value of the function in the immediate window and suddenly everything worked.The value of the function was not pointing to the empty string.It now pointed to the value it should point.Thanks for the immediate response though.Both the methods seem to be so correct.